# How to implement cross browser min-height and max-height at the same time?

Tags: html, css

If only to implement max-height:

```
max-height:200px;
 height:auto !important;
 height:200px;
 overflow:hidden;
```

if only to implement min-height:

```
min-height:40px;
height:auto!important;
height:40px;
```

See?There is conflict on height!

What's the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to go pure CSS, I'd go the conditional stylesheet route.

However, my preferred solution is just a touch of jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready() (function() {
    if ($("#division").height() > 200) {
        $("#division").height('200px');
    }
    if ($("#division").height() < 40) {
        $("#division").height('40px');
    }
  }
```

Comment: won'y be so beautiful for those users of yours without javascript, though.

Comment: Yea @omg : the simplicity and beauty of wrong code. What about window resizing AFTER the $(document).ready()? Never mind. Or try to put this into an eMail newsletter (no JS at all)...

Answer (score 3):

i assume you write your CSS like this because you want to support Internet Explorer, which does not recognize min-height max-height.

I suggest you move everything into a conditional stylesheet, that only IE will use:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Read [this](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) for more info on this technique. It's the only proper way to deal with Explorer's issues.

Comment: Yes, but what do you put **in** that stylesheet to get IE to support both a minimum height *and* a maximum height?

Comment: I'm going to ask the same question.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. Just live with it and set the height for IE users (so in your IE-only.css stylesheet) to 200px. Then use your jquery trick so you degrade gracefully for most users, without losing on functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a technique derived from an [article on min-height and max-height in IE](http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/01/16/maximum-and-minimum-height-and-width-in-internet-explorer/):

```
* html div#division { 
   height: expression(this.scrollHeight >= 200 ? "200px" : this.scrollHeight <= 40 ? "40px" : "auto");
}

div#division {
   min-height: 40px;
   max-height: 200px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

The `expression` value works only in IE, but works back as far as IE 5. Here, it keeps the `height` property within the desired range. Standards-compliant browsers will ignore this declaration, and instead use the `min-height` and `max-height` rules.

Caveat: JavaScript must be enabled in IE for `expression` to work.

The technique you are currently using might be preferred by the "use only pure CSS" crowd, but IMHO it is obscure and brittle. Using a non-standard, IE-specific value makes it clear that the code is written specifically to support IE. Not only is this self-documenting, it also makes it easier to migrate the IE-specific code into separate CSS files.

Comment: Don’t use `expression`. It needs to be evaluated on any event (mouse move, scroll, key stroke, etc.).

Comment: @Gumbo, I did not know that. Thanks! I'm starting to like mabwi's jQuery answer now, especially since `expression` requires scripting to be enabled anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
min-height:500px;
height:auto !important;
height:500px;
```

Comment: A little more explanation why this would work, would be helpful.

Comment: This works because IE treats "height" how "min-height" is supposed to be treated. (fingers crossed. Its bloody IE.)